# No such module 'FirebaseUI' iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Podfile

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'FirebaseUI'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
```

In my ViewController.swift i have

```
import FirebaseUI
```

error i get is

```
No such module 'FirebaseUI'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you might be opening the Xcode project instead of the Xcode workspace created by CocoaPods.

After you run `pod install`, CocoaPads will create an Xcode workspace (it has a .xcworkspace extension). You need to open this instead of the Xcode project (with the .xcodeproj) extension, otherwise Xcode will not be able to find the frameworks in your pod file.

Oh, and one more thing... Even if you open the workspace, you will still get this error until after your first compile. This is because the frameworks specified in the Podfile will not yet be built. After your first build all should be well!

Comment: I'll check it ASAP as I'm away for the weekend but sounds likely.